# Load file inside a constructor, bad practice?

Tags: java, design-patterns

Is this a bad practice?
I've seen few peoples say that constructor should not do the real work.

```java
class FooConfig {
   public FooConfig(File file) {
      loadFile(file);
   }

   private void loadFile(File file) {
      // do something...
   } 
}
```

Or I should do this instead?

```java
class FooConfig {
   private final File file;

   public FooConfig(File file) {
      this.file = file;
   }

   public void loadFile(File file) {
      // do something...
   }
}
```

```java
FooConfig config = new FooConfig(file);
config.loadFile();
```

Thank you.

Comment: This depends. As an example, `new FileInputStream("does not exist")` will immediately raise an exception. This is easy to interpret in the context of what your class is about; and you would know.

Answer (score 1):

It depends, but in general, unless you know what you're doing, there is nothing wrong in it. It's actually more simpler to initialize in the constructor. This is what the caller of your code would expect anyway: an object accepting a file is expected to process it upon initialization. The caller would also avoid bugs where they forget to call the initialization method manually.

I'm pretty sure that if you look at third-party libraries (e.g. Spring), you will find occurrences of such constructors accepting files. For example, [`FileSystemXmlApplicationContext`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.html) offers a parameter to do a "refresh" based on the input files, so that the user can have control over the refreshing of the context (either the constructor does it, or the refresh has to be done manually).